# Mongoose: How to exclude virtual id field during populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to exclude the virtual id field that Mongoose sets.

```
var Bar = new Schema({ body: String });    
var Foo = new Schema({ bars: type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Bar' });

Foo
.find({..query...})
.populate('bars', 'body -_id')
.exec(function(err, foos){
   console.log(foos); // { bars: [{id: null, body: 'body string'}] }
});
```

How do I get rid of that 'id' field? It's null anyway since I've excluded _id in populate?

Comment: Does `'body -_id -id'` work?

Comment: No it removed _id but left id assigned as null.

Comment: WiMantis' solution works for me!

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the virtual `id` field in your schema's options ([see documentation here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-id)). In your case, it would look like this :

```
var Bar = new Schema({ body: String }, { id: false });
```